# Run time error '1004' VBA to create pivot table

Tags: excel, runtime-error, pivot-table, vba

I am working on a macro to create a Pivot Table for a dynamic named range "DATA".  I get a "Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed.  From what I see on other posts it may be because I am not referencing a specific sheet?   How would I correct for this?

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Names("DATA")
    .Name = "DATA"
    .RefersToR1C1 = _
    "=OFFSET('Closed Cases'!R1C2,0,0,COUNTA('Closed Cases'!C6),25)"
    .Comment = ""
End With
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    Range("DATA"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "'External Analytics!'R1C15", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("External Analytics").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Resolver")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Comment: Do you have "DATA" already defined as a Named range when running this code ? otherwise, it will throw an error at the first line. At what line are you getting this error ?

Comment: The first with statement names the range and is not showing an error.  I receive the error here:

`ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        Range("DATA"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "'External Analytics!'R1C15", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14`

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Names("DATA").Name = "DATA"`? Huh?

Comment: That is how the macro recorder recorded naming my "data" range. It completes without error.

Comment: @Ryan Hulet try the code in mu answer below' let me know if it works for you

Comment: @Shai Rado, please see the comment on your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming form your post, the the Named Range "DATA" is defined correctly, the code below will create the `PivotTable` according to the data in "DATA" named Range, and the settings you wanted in your post.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DynamicCreatePivot()

Dim wsSheet             As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim PTCache             As PivotCache

' set Pivot destination sheet
Set wsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("External Analytics")

' set Pivot Cache to the data in "DATA" named range
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, "DATA")

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = wsSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3") ' check if "PivotTable3" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' if Pivot Table is not created

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "External Analytics" sheet, start from Cell O1 (R1C15)
    Set PvtTbl = wsSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=wsSheet.Range("O1"), TableName:="PivotTable3")

    'Create the headings and row and column orientation
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Resolver")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
Else ' Pivot Table already created >> in precious code runs
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range (named range "DATA")
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PTCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PTCache returns invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: @RyanHulet it happens after you ran this MACRO already once ? you were able to create the `PivotTable` on your first time running this code ?

Comment: No this was the first time running the code.  was unable to run the code without errors at all.

Comment: that's strange, since you are getting to the `Else` section, which means the `PivotTable` is already created

Comment: it is not processing your dim codes.  does not create a pivot table, it just skips over then returns an error on the else since the pivot table has not been created

Comment: Can u uploaded your file to Dropbox or something and send me the link?